# Android: Google Authentication + Ubertoken

Tags: android, authentication, oauth

Ok, I give up.  Anyone have experience using Google's IssueAuthToken and MergeSession to authenticate with certain Google services that do not have official API access?  In this case I'm trying to get Google bookmarks (from google.com/bookmarks).

I get the SID and LSID using getAuthToken and that works fine.  I then call

```
Uri ISSUE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL = Uri.parse("https://accounts.google.com/IssueAuthToken?service=bookmarks&Session=false");

String url = ISSUE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL.buildUpon()
                 .appendQueryParameter("SID", sid)
                 .appendQueryParameter("LSID", lsid)
                 .build().toString();
```

I receive the "ubertoken".

I then do a GET to MergeSession and that's where it all goes wrong:

```
String url2 = "https://accounts.google.com/MergeSession?source=chrome&uberauth="+uberToken+"&service=bookmarks&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fbookmarks%2F";
HttpGet getCookies = new HttpGet(url2);
```

Looking through the headers of getCookies I am not seeing the extra cookies I should see, and I also see things like `X-Frame-Options: DENY`.

Help (please)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay friends, here we go.  It seems the above is now unreliable/broken at least occasionally as of August 2013.  This is how I'm doing it now and it seems to work.  It tries the above first, and if it fails, goes on to method #2.

```
  final Account acct = am.getAccountsByType("com.google")[acctid];
  final String tokenType = "weblogin:service=bookmarks&continue=https://www.google.com/bookmarks/";

    am.getAuthToken(acct, tokenType, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            try {
                final String accessToken = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                if (accessToken.contains("WILL_NOT_SIGN_IN")) {
                    am.getAuthToken(acct, "SID", null, MainActivity.this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                            try {
                                sid = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                                finish();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            am.getAuthToken(acct, "LSID", null, MainActivity.this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                                @Override
                                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                                    try {
                                        lsid = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                                    } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                                        finish();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    Thread t = new Thread() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {
                                                Uri ISSUE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/accounts/IssueAuthToken?service=gaia&Session=false");
                                                Uri TOKEN_AUTH_URL = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/accounts/TokenAuth");

                                                final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                                httpclient.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
                                                httpclient.getParams().setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true);

                                                String url = ISSUE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("SID", sid).appendQueryParameter("LSID", lsid).build().toString();
                                                HttpPost getUberToken = new HttpPost(url);
                                                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getUberToken);

                                                String uberToken = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

                                                final String accessToken2 = TOKEN_AUTH_URL.buildUpon()
                                                        .appendQueryParameter("source", "android-browser")
                                                        .appendQueryParameter("auth", uberToken)
                                                        .appendQueryParameter("continue", "https://www.google.com/bookmarks/").build().toString();

                                                //do stuff
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                                    t.start();
                                }
                            }, null);
                        }
                    }, null);
                } else {             
                    //do stuff
                }
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                finish();                 
            }
        }
    }, null);
```